# pickadate.js disable all days except 3

Tags: jquery, date, pickadate

ive currently got an installation of pickadate.js. im trying to disable all days except 3.

im using the onOpen event to block out the days, however no matter which way I apply it,

the only thing i appear to be able to do is block out all the days, using disable : true and when i try to explicitly apply the allowed days it blocks them instead.

Any ideas on how to do this muchly appreciated

```
$('input.datepicker').pickadate({
    today : '',
    clear : 'Clear',
    format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    clear: 'Clear selection',
    labelMonthNext: 'Go to the next month',
    labelMonthPrev: 'Go to the previous month',
    labelMonthSelect: 'Pick a month from the dropdown',
    labelYearSelect: 'Pick a year from the dropdown',
    editable : false,
    // disable the other days in the calendar except this one. 1 - 7 are the way days are dealt with
    onOpen : function(){ 
        var picker = this ;
        var current = picker.get('id')
        var allowed_days = $('#' + current).attr('data-disabled-days');
            disabled_days = JSON.parse("[" + allowed_days + "]");                                   
            picker.set('disable',disabled_days);
    }
});
```

Comment: What exaclty does your attribute `data-disabled-days` contain? Does it have `true` as the first value as [documentation of pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm#disable-dates-all) says?

Comment: yes it does contain the exact format. true,1,2,3

Comment: Can you put an example online demonstrating the problem, e.g. on jsfiddle?